# Localhost not working in Chrome on Ubuntu, firefox does work

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, localhost

When I try to access http://localhost:8080 in Chrome (version 122.0.6261.111) on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, I get the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached 
The webpage at http://localhost:8080 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

- When I try to access the same URI in Firefox, it works.
- When I try to access http://127.0.0.1:8080 in Chrome, it works

Here is a list of things I tried:

- verified localhost is in my /etc/hosts file
- cleared browser cache (including cookies, cached files ...)
- cleared host cache in chrome://net-internals/#dns
- cleared domain security policies in chrome://net-internals/#hsts
- disabled cache in the network cache of the developer tools
- tried chrome without cors (--disable-web-security)
- tried incognito mode in Chrome, but same issue
- tried brave browser, but same issue
- reinstall chrome

Comment: What OS are you using? If it's Windows, have you tried running Chrome as an administrator? I know it's a silly thing to ask, but who knows? Might work.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu (as indicated in the question)